# Algorithm for generating Multinomial random variables

Tags: python, random, multinomial

I would like to generate random numbers from a Multinomial distribution. Say you have n and p_1,...p_m such that sum of p_1, ...,p_m is equal to 1. I know n and p_1,...,p_m values. Ideally, I would like to write a code in Python; but a general algorithm would definitely suffice. Obviously, output of my code would be m random numbers x_1,...,x_m such that sum of x_1,..., x_m is n.

Comment: Use `numpy`: [`numpy.random.multinomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html)

Comment: @Blender: Thank you for your comment. Is there anyway that I can get the algorithm for generating these numbers?

Comment: See [To simulate a multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#To_simulate_a_multinomial_distribution).